# iOS - How to display the same table view after selecting an item

Tags: ios, uitableview

My iOS app is current transferring control to a detail view when an item in a UITableView is selected. This ia a quiz program, and I'd like to change the app so that it just redisplays the same table view with the correct answer highlighted when a row is selected. What's a good approach for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not clear to me if you know why the detail view is appearing. So I'll explain just in case. If you are giving control to a detail view is because somewhere in your code you are pushing that detail view. It depends on what kind of `UITableViewCell` you are using. If you are using one of the defaults styles, your detail view is probably been pushed in either:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

or

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

If you are using a custom cell, then you need to look for the method in charge of pushing 
that detail view.

I think a good approach would be to:

1. Remove that pushing wherever it is.
2. Not to use an `UITableViewCellAccessoryType, if you are using one.
3. Do something similar to the following on your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

   - Find the row for the right answer in your model array, according to tapped cell.
   - Use that row number to generate an `NSIndexPath`.
   - Use that `NSIndexPath` to find the correct cell with `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`
   - Call `setSelected:animated:` on that cell to highlight it.

NOTE: If your quiz has more answers than the amount of `UITableViewCells` that fit in the screen you should scroll your `UITableView` to the right answer for better UX.

Comment: The problem is that cellForRowAtIndexPath isn't called when a selection is made.

Comment: because that's not the method the delegate calls, it calls `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.